# blank custom request header on the server side

Tags: php, jquery, apache2

I am sending request header using ajax jquery as follows

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.example.com/index.php",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "GET",
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X_REST_USERNAME", "XXXX");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X_REST_PASSWORD", "XXXX");
        console.log(xhr);
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {

            alert(data);

    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

    console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
    }

});
```

i can see the above request header in firebug  ,but at the server end on a php page when i try to access following variables it gives me `blank` , i tired dumping and printing variable in php but there isnt any entry for it

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REST_USERNAME']
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REST_PASSWORD']
```

Comment: just a hunch, add `console.log(xhr.setRequestHeader("X_REST_USERNAME", "XXXX");` and see what comes back? Use google chrome developer toolkit to monitor the requests.

Comment: Do you have $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REST_USERNAME'] and $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REST_PASSWORD'] defined ?

Comment: Defined where ? and yes i am trying to access it  $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REST_USERNAME'] and $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REST_PASSWORD'] like this only using HTTP prifix

Answer (score 0):

```
$_REQUEST['X_REST_USERNAME'];
$_REQUEST['X_REST_PASSWORD'];
```

Comment: $_REQUEST is populated with the contents of $_POST, $_GET, and $_COOKIE by default. There is no way the request headers will be present in that array.

Comment: isn't it `$_GET['X_REST_USERNAME'];` ? He sends a GET-request right..?

Comment: If your using headers, can't you login to websites using http://username:password@website.com ?

Answer (score 0):

In case of apache, use [apache_request_headers](http://in.php.net/apache_request_headers).

```
$headers = apache_request_headers();
echo $headers['X_REST_USERNAME'];
echo $headers['X_REST_PASSWORD'];
```